# Display Image CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a problem displaying images in the bottom of my web page.

This is what I want :

[image: Wanted]

But it fails to load the images.

This is my code :

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.scss">
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header class="header">
            Mon App de Météo
        </header>
        <section class="view">

        </section>
        <nav class="nav">
            <a href="#home"><i class="home"></i></a>
            <a href="#about"><i class="about"></i></a>
        </nav>
    </body>
</html>
```

**style.css**

```
.header{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #11a7ab;
}

.nav{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #4f597b;
}

.home{
    background-image: url('../img/icon/home.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.about{
    background-image: url('../img/icon/about.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

a{
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
```

And this is the hierarchy :

[image: hierarchy]

The console doesn't show any errors which makes me wonder what did I do wrong ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that is all your CSS, the problem is that the empty `<i>` elements have no size, so the background images have a 0x0 space to work with. Solution: give the i elements the size of the icons explicitly.

Comment: That worked! And I also had to add a `display : inline-block;`

Comment: OK. If this works, can you click the check mark to the left to mark it as the solution? That way, the question will no longer show up in the list of unsolved problems.